# route navigation is not working in angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I am working on a login and home component in my angular app.

Login service is validating the username and password of the user.

After successful login, it should redirect user to the home page.

But router redirect is not working properly.

**login component**

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { User } from 'src/app/shared/models/user';

import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  userName: FormControl;
  password: FormControl;
  loginFormGroup: FormGroup;
  loginError: boolean;
  errorMessage: string;
  messageString: string;

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userName = new FormControl("", [Validators.required]);
    this.password = new FormControl("", [Validators.required]);
    this.loginFormGroup = new FormGroup({
      userName: this.userName,
      password: this.password
    });
  }

  login() {
    this.loginError = false;
    if (this.loginFormGroup.valid) {
      let user: User = new User();
      user.userId = this.userName.value;
      user.password = this.password.value;
      this.authService.login(user)
        .subscribe(res => 
        {
          console.log(res)
          this.router.navigate(["home"])
          console.log("res")
        },
        error =>
        {
          console.log(error)
        });
    }
  }
}
```

and **login service**

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { share } from "rxjs/operators";
import { environment} from 'src/environments/environment';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
import { User } from 'src/app/shared/models/user';

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AuthService {
  user: User;
  resp=401;

  get userDetail(): User {
    return this.user;
  }

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
  }


  login(user: User): Observable<any> {

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("userId", user.userId);
    formData.append("password", user.password);

    return this.http.get<any>(url+"Validate_Login_User",{
      headers: new HttpHeaders(),
      params: new HttpParams().set("User_Id","user.userId")
    })

  }

}
```

**routes**

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { AuthGuard } from "./authentication/services/auth.guard";

import { LoginComponent } from "./authentication/login/login.component";
import { LayoutComponent } from "./shared/components/layout/layout.component";
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from "./shared/components/page.not.found.component";
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: "home",
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        //childroutes
      },
      {
        //childroutes
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: "**", component: PageNotFoundComponent },
  { path: "Menu", component: MenuComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      onSameUrlNavigation: "ignore",
      useHash: true,
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**console log in login component**

[image]

even though the console is printing success, route navigate is not happening and its still in login page

Comment: I see you have a Guard on `/home`. Where do you stock the Auth token ?

Comment: Hi, have the same Problem but, the suggestions on this site did not bring success.  app-routing.module.ts:
<code>    {path: 'person', loadChildren: () => import('@barbara/person').then(module => module.PersonModule)},
</code>

then in the person module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your code with the following piece of code, that should work.

```
 this.loginError = false;
    if (this.loginFormGroup.valid) {
      let user: User = new User();
      user.userId = this.userName.value;
      user.password = this.password.value;
      this.authService.login(user)
        .subscribe(res => 
        {
          console.log(res)
          this.router.navigate(["/home"])
          console.log("res")
        },
        error =>
        {
          console.log(error)
        });
    }
  }
```

Edited:

Please replace your ngModule with the below code:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: true,
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

Comment: For once remove authGuard from the router, and check. If it works properly then go and verify your service.

Comment: removing authGuard is working but child routes are not accessible

Comment: Hi, can you add a bit explanation to your code ? Why does your code should work ?

Comment: When you are using the child routers, the url navigation do contain the parent route, so it detects that the urls are same and would prevent the app from routing, as you have configured it false.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
 this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
```